# Syntax error at '{'; expected '}' when using nagios in puppet

Tags: nagios, puppet, syntax

It's a big problem to me, because I'm not familiar with puppet.

**ERROR on the puppetmaster:**

```
debug: importing '/etc/puppet/manifests/nodes/group-1.pp'
err: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '{'; expected '}' at /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes/group-1.pp:6
```

**ERROR on the puppet client:**

> err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at
>   '{'; expected '}' at /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes/group-1.pp:6

in group-1.pp:

```
node 'group1'
{
        include ntp 

        class { 'nagios::host':           #this is line 6
                nodename => $clientcert,
                appname => 'test',
        }   
}
```

nagios::host in module module/nagios/host.pp
code are here:

```
class nagios::host($nodename, $hostgroup) {


  file { '/usr/lib/nagios/plugins':
    mode    => "755",
    require => Package["nagios-plugins"],
  }

  ...

    @@nagios_service { "${nodename}_check_ssh":
      ensure => present,
      use => 'generic-service',
      host_name => "${nodename}",
      notification_interval => 60,
      flap_detection_enabled => 0,
      service_description => "SSH",
      check_command => "check_ssh",
      target => "/etc/nagios3/services.d/${nodename}.cfg",
    } 
}
```

and the file module/nagios/init.pp is blank

How could I fix it ?

Comment: What's in modules/ntp/ntp.pp ( or similar )

Comment: It's ntp service, it runs ok

Comment: Where is `appname` parameter from?

Answer (score 2):

Puppet 0.25 does not support parametrized classes, you must upgrade to puppet > 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

That's solved. 
The puppet master version is 0.25, defautl on ubuntu 10.04 LTS. 
I've upgrade it to 2.7.14 , and it runs ok.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar problem, it turned out to be simple syntax problem. Somewhere in a document I had a syntax error but I showed the error to me almost at the end of that document. So I'd advise yoCheck your parentheses, quotes and commas.